# How could I change the numeration style in table of contens in beamer (Latex)?

Tags: latex, beamer, tableofcontents

Hello I am new at beamer (overleaf), so I have learned very much, so I would like to change the design of the numeration in table of contents. I mean with that (see picture attached):

[image]

I would like to change to a square, or simply the number. Anyone knows others styles? I am using the `\usetheme{CambridgeUS}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `sections/subsections in toc` template to change to e.g. a square or plain numbered sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]
%\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[sections numbered]

\begin{document}
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```