# How could I list the subsections in beamer (table of contens)?

Tags: latex, beamer, tableofcontents

Hello I trying to list the subsections in table of contents (beamer), but I can't get the result ? Anyone knows how to do it ?

My code (I am using the \usetheme{CambridgeUS}):

```
\documentclass[handout,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}%
\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse} 
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title[]{\textcolor{black}{\vskip 1.5cm\textbf {Title}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introducción}
\begin{frame}{Introducción}
\subsection{sismos lentos}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] which shows us which theme you use.

Comment: If I use the code, I gave you 2 days ago, I get this subsection layout by default.

Comment: And please stop adding the `flutter-beamer` tag. This has nothing to do with latex beamer. I already edited your previous post, but you added it again for this one :(

Comment: Ok, sorry, but I had no more options (tags) to relate my questions, I will not use it. Thanks

Comment: Please make a compilable example. We don't have access to all the files you include. The code you show neither has a toc, nor subsections.

Comment: I changed the code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never use sectioning commands like `\section` or `\subsection` within a frame. They must be used outside the frame.

Apart from this problem, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094309/2777074 to get squares in the toc:

```
\documentclass[handout,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}%
\usepackage{
%etoolbox, 
xparse} 
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title[]{\textcolor{black}{\vskip 1.5cm\textbf {Title}}}


\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduccion}
\subsection{sismos lentos}
\begin{frame}{Introduccion}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]